# How to get a list of all the Product Attributes associated with the Products displayed on a Product Category Page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

On the Product Category pages a set of Products are displayed using a HTML template with context from the view.py. In the sidebar of the HTML page, I want to display all the Product Attributes associated with the available Products on the page ([here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HutjF.png)).

In other words, I want to access the Product Attributes in the template file of the Product Categories.

The Product Attributes have the Product Categories as foreign keys, as seen in the code below.

```
# views.py #
class ProductCategoryListView(ListView):

template_name = "products/product_categories.html" # Default fetch template location: <blog>/<modelname>_list.html
#queryset = Product.objects.filter(categories_id = ) # e.g. id=1

def get_queryset(self):
    self.category = get_object_or_404(ProductCategory, slug=self.kwargs["slug"]) #id=self.kwargs["id"]
    return Product.objects.filter(categories=self.category)   # categories_id=self.category.id
    #return Product.objects.filter(categories__contains = self.category.get_descendants(include_self=True))

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # Context of Product Category
    context['full_name'] = self.category.full_name
    context['ancestors'] = self.category.get_ancestors
    context['category'] = self.category
    context['descendant_count'] = self.category.get_descendant_count
    context['descendants'] = self.category.get_descendants(include_self=False)
    context['siblings'] = self.category.get_siblings(include_self=False)
    context['filter'] = ProductFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())

    attributes = []
    for product in Product.objects.filter(categories=self.category):
        attributes.append(...)
    context['attributes'] = attributes   # Get attributes of the category

    return context

# models.py #
class ProductAttributes(models.Model):
"""
The Product Attributes Table contains product attributes
or features for the product category.
"""

product_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Product Attributes"
    verbose_name_plural = "Product Attributes"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rephrased my question, and it was solved here, in case anyone is curious:
[In this setup, how do I inner join Product, ProductAttributes, and ProductAttributesValue? [Django models & view]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68090051/in-this-setup-how-do-i-inner-join-product-productattributes-and-productattrib)