# In this setup, how do I inner join Product, ProductAttributes, and ProductAttributesValue? [Django models & view]

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

The first line of views.py is the Products queryset that I want to inner join with the next line of the views.py (the inner join of ProductAttributes and ProductAttributesValue)

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ProductAttributes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ProductAttributesValue(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttributes, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)


# views.py - just code fragments
Product.objects.filter(categories=self.category) # Products only in selected category

products_att = ProductAttributes.objects.filter(productattributesvalue__isnull=False) # Inner join of ProductAttributes and ProductAttributeValues - sent to context in view
products_att = products_att.values("id", "name", "productattributesvalue__value")   
context['attribute_values'] = products_att
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
Product.objects.filter(
    categories=self.category,
    productattributesvalue__attributes__isnull=False
).values(
    'title',
    'productattributesvalue__attributes__name'
)
```

This will produce a `QuerySet` of dictionaries that contains the title and the name of the productattribute that is related to that product through the `ProductAttributesValue` junction table.

It might however be better to work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to obtain `Product`s with an extra attribute `.attr_name` that contains the name of the product attributes. A `Product` will be repeated for each related `ProductAttributes`:

```
from django.db.models import F

Product.objects.filter(
    productattributesvalue__attribute__isnull=False
).annotate(
    attr_name=F('productattributesvalue__attribute__name')
)
```

Comment: Looks good! I actually just tried doing this:

products = ProductAttributesValue.objects.select_related('product', 'attribute')

And it seems to work in giving a total queryset from the view to the template. Do you think there are any downsides to using this solution?

Also, I want the template file to iterate over each Attributes, and for each Attribute list its corresponding AttributeValues. Do you see a smart way of doing that in the template?

{% for attribute in attributes %}
       {{ attribute }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: @FrederikFaarup: the main downside I think with all these approaches is that the same data (for the same product) is retrieved multiple times, and thus will result in useless bandwidth. Likely using `.prefetch_related(...)` can limit the bandwidth.

Comment: I see. So in the inner join, the Products have to be filtered to only contains the ones in the given category.  The following code works for the on the Products:

.filter(categories=self.category)

How can I incorporate this in one of the solutions?

Comment: Oh, I just realised how to - and that your first solution includes the filter. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Hmm, the solutions don't seem to work. Using .filter(productattributesvalue__attributes__isnull=False) 
gives the following error:
 Related Field got invalid lookup: attributes

Comment: It is `__attribute`, not `__attributes`.

Comment: Ah I see, it works now. How do I index the values in template?

Comment: @FrederikFaarup: normally you don't. The view should process the data in such a way that the template can easily render it. You can use `{{ foo.0 }}` to obtain the first item of the list for example, but you can not work with a variable `i` that will use the index like `{{ foo.i }}`.

Comment: So I'm getting a list for each product containing product title, attribute name and attribute value (because I added this to your code).

I want to in my template to show a list of attributes, and then their corresponding values, like:

color: grey, black white etc | size: 10cm, 20cm, etc

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking.. Perhaps I should iterate over each element in the list in views.py and create a dictionary with attributes and keys and values as values, and then just send that dict to the view

Answer (score 0):

let me put my 5 cents in. :)
I would advise you to use a ManyToMany relationship in implementation of your model. It will be a way easier for you to work with the model, and what is quite important, you can browse a numerous documentation guides dedicated to many-to-many relationship.

That is what your model is supposed to be, when speaking Django modelling language:

```
# models.py

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attributes = ManyToManyField(Attribute)
```

The relationship model ProductAttribute linking product_id with attribute_id would be created by Django automatically behind the scene.

As you can see you already have the inner join and it is absolutely free.
Other goodies and techniques can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I see what you mean, and I alway appreciate feedback! But keep in mind that I need both a model for Attributes, e.g. color, size etc, and a model for AttributeValues, e.g. grey, 20 cm etc.

Would I not lose this information using your approach?

Comment: I think it should work for you, because it is identical to your model, except, that in your model, you are not defining the ManyToMany relationship, and trying to replicate on your own, what you otherwise would be getting for free. As I mention, Django creates AttributeValue table for you, it looks exactly like in your spec. If your need more than this, it is also possible to specify AttributeValue table manually, defining a ManyToMany relationship. All in all, just go and try it out, many-to-many it is quite useful technique when you work with Django.